# VTK: Aligning two actors

Tags: c++, ios, vtk

I am experimenting and currently have two objects in an iOS app using the VES/VTK framework and can move the vesActors in the scene. What I don't understand is how I can take the position of one object and apply it to a second object. In other words make two planes parallel basically planar homography within the VTK framework using actors, mappers, and/or transforms. Are there any examples of this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can pick 3 points on/relative to your planes, you can use vtkLandmarkTransform (http://www.vtk.org/doc/nightly/html/classvtkLandmarkTransform.html), as demonstrated here: http://www.vtk.org/Wiki/VTK/Examples/Cxx/PolyData/AlignFrames

Comment: The issue is getting this to work in VES and ultimately the reason why working with VES is such a royal pain. I can try it out though. I can't wait for VTK to take over iOS support.